# Email - bulletproof background image

Tags: html, outlook, html-table, html-email

I'm coding up HTML emails and am trying to get a background banner image to render somewhat correctly across Outlook 2010, 11, 13, 16. Using this currently - http://backgrounds.cm/. 
My issue is that Outlook 2010 and 2013 seem to zoom in on the background image.

My code:

```
<td background="https://someKitten.jpg" width="600" height="185" valign="top">

                      <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                      <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:600px;height:185px;">
                        <v:fill type="tile" src="https://someKitten.jpg" />
                        <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
                      <![endif]-->
                      <div>
                      </div>
                      <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                        </v:textbox>
                      </v:rect>
                      <![endif]-->
                </td>
```

this seems to be a known issue but I'm not coming across any fixes. https://www.campaignmonitor.com/forums/topic/7953/bulletproof-background-images-enlarging-in-outlook/

Answer (score 4):

and...fixed.

for anyone else struggling with this issue, set fill type to "frame"

```
<v:fill type="frame" src="https://someKitten.jpg" />
```